# Is $S = \{(x,y) : y = e^x\}$ is convex or not?

Tags: convex-analysis

If $S = \{(x,y) : y = e^x\}$ was convex, the following relation holds
\begin{align}
&t y_1 + (1-t) y_2 = e^{t x_1 + (1-t) x_2} \tag{1}\\[2mm]
\Longleftrightarrow \quad & t e^{x_1} + (1-t) e^{x_2} - e^{t x_1 + (1-t) x_2} = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
for any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $t \in (0,1)$.

- Is my definition of convexity correct?

For $t=0.5$ (2) becomes
\begin{align}
&0.5(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2}) - e^{0.5(x_1 + x_2)}  = 0 \tag{3}\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad &e^{x_1} + e^{x_2} - 2e^{0.5(x_1 + x_2)}  = 0 \tag{4}\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad &(e^{0.5 x_1} - e^{0.5 x_2})^2 = 0 \tag{5}
\end{align}

where (5) is a contradiction (do you guys use any symbols for that matter?) and thus $S$ is *not* convex.

- Can we verify the statement in a general manner with $t$ being free?

---

Now show that $S' = \{(x,y) : y \geq e^x\}$ is convex. (5) then becomes
\begin{align}
(e^{0.5 x_1} - e^{0.5 x_2})^2 \geq 0 \tag{6}
\end{align}

which is true and thus $S'$ is convex. Again, I'd like to show this in a rather general way.

### Edit

I added 'If it is not convex, give a counterexample.' to the title. I was just wondering if we can construct a general counterexample without specifying some values for $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ and $t$.

Comment: No, I thought that this is the definition for convexity here, i.e. any linear combination of two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ must be a linear combination of $y_1$ and $y_2$, *if* $\{(x,y) : y=e^x\}$ was convex which is apparently not the case, thus the equation is not true or extremly wrong for that matter.

Comment: If we have the two points: $(x_1, e^{x_1})$ and $(x_2, e^{x_2})$, the convex combination, for some scalar $t \in (0,1)$ is $(tx_1+(1-t)x_2, te^{x_1} + (1-t)e^{x_2})$. This can't be simplified further...

Comment: yes, ok, your application of the def. of convexity at the top is fine.

Comment: Not at all, this is a definition of linearity ! Convexity is when inequality $\ge$ holds.

Comment: What about $\{(x,y) : x = y\}$? This is a convex set, isn't it?

Comment: @YvesDaoust He's talking about convexity of a set, not convexity of a function.

Comment: For a counterexample, if we're really just talking about the graph of $y=e^x$, I don't see why you couldn't just mention something about secant lines.

Comment: @MatthewGunn: oooops, right. Then the answer's easy.

Answer (score 3):

It is not convex. $(-1,{1 \over e}), (1,e) \in S$, but
${1 \over 2} ((-1,{1 \over e})+ (1,e)) = (0, {1 \over 2}(e+{1 \over e})) \notin S$.

Suppose $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in S'$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. If $f(x) = e^x$
we see that $f''(x) >0$, hence $f$ is convex function. Then
$e^{\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2} \le \lambda e^{x_1} + (1-\lambda) e^{x_2}$ and so we have
$e^{\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2} \le \lambda e^{x_1} + (1-\lambda) e^{x_2} \le \lambda y_1+(1-\lambda) y_2$ and so we see that
$({\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2}, (\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda) y_2)) \in S'$ and
so $S'$ is convex.

Comment: He probably means $ y \geq e^x $. Then the convexity of the epigraph follows immediately from the convexity of $e^x$.

Comment: Well, $S$ is not convex, but $S'$ is. I don' think the question was ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, now I see this S, S' stuff. You're right. Maybe I'm half asleep, or maybe he keeps editing the question :P

Answer (score 1):

For "Show that $S' = \left\{(x,y) : y \geq e^x\right\}$ is a convex set"

You can argue:

1. $e^x$ is a convex function.
2. The [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of a convex function is a convex set.

Note that $S = \left\{(x,y) : y = e^x\right\}$ is not a convex set. It trivially fails the def. of convexity. You can use any two points and any scalar $t \in (0,1)$ to generate a point that should be in $S$ (if it were convex) but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Take $t=\frac12$.

$$e^{(x_1+x_2)/2}=\sqrt{e^{x_1}e^{x_2}}\ne\frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}2.$$

Indeed, the converse would imply, by squaring

$$\left(\frac{e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}}2\right)^2=0$$which is false.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S'$ is actually known as the *epigraph* of the function $f(x) = e^x$.  The epigraph of $f$ (denoted as $\mathrm{epi}(f)$) is convex if and only if the function $f$ is convex, which is true since $f''(x) = e^x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

"Can we verify the statement in a general manner with $t$ being free?"

Your set $S$ equals the graph of a function, and this graph is convex iff the function is affine:

If $f : X \to Y$ is a function between linear spaces and $S = \{(x,y) : y = f(x)\}$ is convex, we have
$$f( \lambda \, x_1 + (1-\lambda) \, x_2 ) = \lambda \, f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) \, f(x_2)$$
for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Now, we show that $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ is linear. Indeed, the above equation with $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = 0$ shows
$$g( \lambda \, x ) = \lambda \, g(x)$$
for $\lambda \in (0,1]$. Using $x_1 = x/\lambda$, $x_2 = 0$ shows
$$g( x) = \lambda \, g(x/\lambda)$$
for $\lambda \in (0,1]$. Hence, $g$ is positively homogeneous and it remains to show the additivity. To this end, we take $\lambda = 1/2$ in the above equation and get
$$\frac12 \, g(x_1 + x_2) = g(\frac12 \, x_1 + \frac12 \, x_2) = \frac12 \, g(x_1) + \frac12 \, g(x_2).$$
This shows the additivity. Hence, $g$ is linear and $f$ is affine.

To apply to your situation, you simply have to note that $x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^x$ is not affine.